# Creating Online Document Reader, editor

Tags: c#, asp.net, ms-word

I want to build a online document reader which is a part of my project. I want to work with MS Word document where user have some access to the documents, according to the access he/she have (will be able to edit the document and save). I want to make it as other online documents there like Safari Online Book Reader or Google Book Reader where there is no functionality of right clicking and saving the document, I want to do the same for the users who have only readonly functionality and to give editting options to those who have editting access.

So Let me know how should I go for it. As MS Word API is easy to use I want to use it for this purpose. I want to code that in .Net (c#)

Answer (score 0):

You want to create ETL(Extract ,Transform , Load) package to acess .doc , .xls , .docx , .xlsx files. you can get data from doc files and write doc files by C# .

Check that link given below.

http://danajaatcse.wordpress.com/2010/05/03/building-a-simple-etl-package-using-ms-sql-integration-services/

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa192487(office.11).aspx